# Pre-order (depth-first) traversal of a closure table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a tree of comments and its [closure table](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back/68):

```
create table comment (
    id serial primary key,
    author varchar(100) not null,
    content text not null
);

create table closure (
    ancestor integer not null references comment (id),
    descendant integer not null references comment (id) on delete cascade,
    depth integer not null,
    primary key (ancestor, descendant)
);
```

I want to get the subtree of all comments under the comment with ID `4`. It's not too hard to do a breadth-first traversal of a comment thread:

```
select comment.*, closure.depth
from comment
inner join closure on closure.descendant = comment.id
where ancestor = 4
order by depth asc;
```

**How can I do a pre-order (depth-first) traversal of the comment thread?**

(I realize that doing a pre-order traversal is easy with nested sets, but I'm specifically curious how to do it with a closure table.)

Comment: Why are you storing `depth`? It's redundant and could be wrong.

Comment: In addition, the query you show will only retrieve the first comment "under" the comment with id 4. You'll need to use a recursive query to retrieve the whole tree structure.

Comment: I can't answer your query right now (I'm more familiar with the Oracle `connect by` syntax) but maybe the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-with.html) will help you.

Comment: NB In answer to my first comment, you can get the recursive query to calculate the `depth` for you.

Comment: @Colin: I think you misunderstood the purpose of the closure table--the query I gave really will get all comments under #4, not just the immediate children. There's a good illustration on slide 69 of the page I linked.

Answer (score 1):

First, please don't think about this problem in terms of breadth first or depth first.  Ideally you are going to look at this as a series of set operations which build a result set.  The SQLy way to do this is to do something which is sort of like breadth-first but operates on one level of depth at a time.   If you try to do a full breadth first or full depth first approach you will run into performance issues.

**The Best Way**

```
WITH RECURSIVE closure_tree AS (
     SELECT descendent as id, ancestor as parent_id, 0 as depth, descendent::text as path
       FROM closure
      WHERE ancestor = 4
  UNION ALL 
     SELECT c.descendent, ct.id, ct.depth + 1, ct.path || ',' || descendent::text
       FROM closure c
       JOIN closure_tree ct ON ct.id = c.ancestor
)
SELECT c.*, ct.depth, string_to_array(ct.path, ',')::int[]
  FROM comment c
  JOIN closure_tree ct ON c.id = ct.id
 ORDER BY string_to_array(ct.path, ',')::int[];
```

Not tested but that gives you an idea.  Basically it scans the table (index or sequential depending on number of comments) once per depth level, retrieving the full graph breadth on each scan.  Keep in mind that SQL excels at managing sets and so this is really the only sane way to do this.  Of course this means that the closure table should only store direct parent/child relationships.

Note that this returns results in a depth first way, while your query returns results in breadth first.  In order to do this you need to store or generate paths somehow because otherwise you can't get real depth information.  So you could in denormalized fashion add path to your closure table, or you could just grab parent/child relationships and generate this in the query as my example shows.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented preordered traversal in my ruby gem, [closure_tree](http://mceachen.github.io/closure_tree/), and the SQL the gem generates works with both MySQL and PostgreSQL. I believe my implementation is novel—but it's pretty hairy, requires two selects, and requires the ordering column to be numeric and [0-N) where N is the number of siblings, and the order has no gaps.

https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree/blob/master/lib/closure_tree/numeric_deterministic_ordering.rb#L48